# Using Conditional HTML Attributes in Custom ActionLink Helper MVC

Tags: javascript, css, razor, razor-2

I am using a custom HTML action link helper and would like to know if it's possible to implement a Condition Attribute function in the text portion of the action link helper.    I have defined a CSS class to format the li element of my list.  It works when I statically define it in the text portion of the Helper.

However, what I want is to something like this

```
@Html.MyActionLink("<li>Foo\@IsCurrentPage("Page1")\</li>",...
```

Is it possible to insert the function IsCurrentPage in this manner.    I already tried using the HTML attributes of the helper, but it seems to apply to the  when I only want to style the

.  Should I refocus on working through the helpers HTML attributes. Or is using the function the way to do this?

Here is the relevant code.

Helper:

```
 public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string action,
    string controller,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchor.InnerHtml = linkText;
        anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues);
        anchor.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());
    }


    }
```

Helper Implementation:

```
@Html.MyActionLink(
                "<li>Foo</li>",
                "MyAction",
                "MyController",
                null,
                null
                )
```

Conditional Attribute Function:

```
@functions {
public static string CurrentPage(string page)
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Contains(page) ? "active-tab" : null;
}
```

}

Comment: @Html.MyActionLink("<li>Foo\"+@IsCurrentPage("Page1")+"\</li>",...

Comment: Thanks, I figured out (as you were typing likely) that this was just a string that could be treated as a string ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the HTML MyActionLink helper defined the text passed in as a string, I was just dealing with strings.  String can be concatenated together to by using the "+" sign between items to be joined.   The function I using to determine which class to use in the li tag is defined in the Razor notation and could be injected between the two parts of the strings I created.